# jQuery get operation to a php file returns a commented php code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, comments

I'm new in sending data to a server from a client using PHP and AJAX (for the last I'm using jQuery to speed up the things).

The code goes some like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#students").click(function () {
    $.get("/php/listing.php?type=s",function (data, status) {
      $("#main_changer").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Even if listing.php would be just:

```
<?php echo phpversion(); ?>
```

It just returns me

```
<!--?php echo phpversion(); ?-->
```

I'm using Apache2 on Kubuntu 16.04, I installed php this way:

```
sudo apt-get install php
```

I don't know if I have to configure the PHP interpreter on the apache server. I searched the instructions in the php website but the instructions are a little tricky to understand.

Comment: I think you didn't restart Apache, you have to do that to activate PHP

Comment: Still with the same problem. It could be that I installed php before apache?

Comment: that can definitely cause problems.

Comment: I'll reinstall php then. I hope that it works... I know that linux has some issues related to uninstalling and installing again (trash files and things like that).

Comment: Try to adding `console.log(data);` and let us what outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I installed PHP before Apache. I uninstalled both and later I installed Apache before PHP.